# How to force the user to download (Save as dialog) the file which just generated?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, into-outfile

I'm generating a file using the query

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE " . "'c:/myfile.csv'" . " FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' FROM sample
```

My file is now in C:/myfile.csv.  I want the user to download the file. How can I achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+force+download

Comment: Sorry for creating duplicate friends...really sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could :

- Send an HTTP header, to indicate the kind of data you're sending, and that it should be downloaded to a file.
- And, then, send the content of that file.

In PHP, something like this should do the trick :

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="my-file.csv"');  // The name which will be suggested to the user
readfile('c:/myfile.csv');  // outputs the content of the file
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `Content-disposition: attachment` in the header. In php, use header function to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!$fdl=@fopen($fileString,'r')){
die("Cannot Open File!");
} else {
 header("Cache-Control: ");// leave blank to avoid IE errors
 header("Pragma: ");// leave blank to avoid IE errors
 header("Content-type: text/csv");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$fileName."\"");
 header("Content-length:".(string)(filesize($fileString)));
sleep(1);
fpassthru($fdl);
}
```